# problem with loading client object model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model

I am using JavaScript Client object model to get rootWeb and check permissions of current user. So I have used ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded in my MasterPage to wait for sp.js. The problem is when I go to some pages for example AllItems.aspx (click a document library) sp.js is not loaded and my funcition will not be fired. I tried to set onDemond for sp.js to false but I got many other "Undefinde or object is null" errors. is there any solution for that? do I need to set ondemond for all javascripts to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute javascript function `LoadSodByKey('sp.js')` on your page. It will load sp.js file with all its dependencies.

http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/08/sharepoint-scripts-on-demand-spsod.html

Comment: do I need to change AllItems.aspx?

Comment: you can try to do it in the end of your master page